# Fancybox2 - different content for tooltip and image title, both from title attribute?

Tags: jquery, attributes, fancybox, title

Both the thumbnail tooltip and the gallery image title are ofc taken from the same title HTML attribute.

I would like to have different content for the thumbnail tooltip and the image title.

eg I would like the tooltip to say: `Sculpture name` and the image title to say: `Sculpture name: Height 123cm`

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks.

My current HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="works" title="Sculpture1 Height:1232mm"     href="images/Sculpture1_large_res.jpg"><imagetag alt="Sculpture1 Height:1232mm" src="images/thumbs/Sculpture1_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a>  

<a class="fancybox" rel="works" title="Sculpture2 Height:1232mm" href="images/Sculpture2_large_res.jpg"><imagetag alt="Sculpture2 Height:1232mm" src="images/thumbs/Sculpture2_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a>
```

UDATE:

My current options;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    'arrows' :    false,
        helpers     : { 
        buttons : {}
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is to set the titles to appear in Fancybox in a hidden `DIV` so my tooltip will show a different content from the title in Fancybox:

**UPDATE** : edited to match your content sample

Your HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="works" title="Sculpture1" href="images/Sculpture1_large_res.jpg"><img alt="Sculpture1 Height:1232mm" src="images/thumbs/Sculpture1_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a>  
<a class="fancybox" rel="works" title="Sculpture2" href="images/Sculpture2_large_res.jpg"><img alt="Sculpture2 Height:1232mm" src="images/thumbs/Sculpture2_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a>
```

Notice the `title` attribute values.

**NEW**: (anywhere within your `<body>` tag) the Fancybox titles:

```
<div id="fancyboxTitles" style="display: none;">
    <div>Sculpture1 Height: 1232mm</div>
    <div>Sculpture2 Height: 1232mm</div>
</div>
```

**Notice** that you have to have a nested `<DIV>` (with the new title) for each image in your gallery.

Then, the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  afterLoad : function() {
   this.title = $("#fancyboxTitles div").eq(this.index).html();
  }
 }); //fancybox
}); // ready
```

**UPDATE #2 (Dec09, 13:43PT)**: Show how to integrate the proposed solution into the original posted script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            arrows :    false,
            helpers : { 
                    buttons : {}
            }, // helpers
            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = $("#fancyboxTitles div").eq(this.index).html();
            } // afterload
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**UPDATE #3 - Jun 03, 2012**: For fancybox v2.0.6, use `beforeShow`  instead of `afterLoad`

Comment: Hi @JFK,but I haven't yet got this to work.  Please would you clarify?  I have posted my current HTML (different to yours) as an edit to my original post.  What do I do with the hidden div, exactly, please?  Thanks.

Comment: @aVo The hidden DIV contains another set of DIVs, ONE per image in your gallery. Each nested DIV will have the title you want display with your images in fancybox. I edited my answer to match your post.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @JFK. That's brilliant! Works.  Now all I need is to integrate your javascript into my existing options.  I have added my current document.ready into my original post.  Please would you show me how to do this.  I did try! :)

Comment: @aVo : see my edited answer (last update) ... and don't forget to check if this is the right (best) answer to your question.

Comment: @ JFK  yes, fantastic, that's got it.  What a difference a comma makes :D  Your answer works very well for me.  My thanks again.

Comment: So don't forget to select this as the right answer to your question

Comment: Ok, I see. That's the tick sign? I've checked it.  I wondered if you were referring to a specific check but couldn't see what you meant initially.  Please do let me know if that is still not what you mean.  Thanks again for your help!