# Trying to replicate custom titles in new version of Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In the old version of Fancybox, I was able to find a code that would allow me custom titles for individual images. But upgrading to Fancybox v.2, I can't figure out how to update the function so it will still work. Yes, I'm a newbie. Help, or a link, would be greatly appreciated.

Old code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a[rel=blanchard_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleShow'     : 'true',
            'overlayShow'       : 'true',
            'overlayColor'      : '#fff',
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.9',
            'showNavArrows'     : 'true',
            'enableEscapeButton'    : 'true',
            'scrolling'     : 'no',
            'onStart':function(currentArray,currentIndex,currentOpts){
                var obj = currentArray[ currentIndex ];
                if ($(obj).next().length)
                this.title = $(obj).next().html();},
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">' + title + '</span>';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

New code ...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancyproject").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'fade',
        nextEffect  : 'fade',
        nextClick   :  true,
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type    : 'inside'
            },
            overlay : {
                opacity : 0.9,
                css : {
                    'background-color' : '#fff'
                }
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the original script where it says 'onStart' that is the javascript that sets the title.

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: So I should change 'onstart' to 'beforeLoad' and 'titleFormat' to ?

Comment: I tried that, and a lot of other things. Spent the last couple hours pouring through stackoverflow looking for answer, and nothing. All I want to do is be able to create a div that contains custom text that will appear instead of the default title when fancybox opens. I will hide the div with display:none with CSS so it does not appear on the site. Help please, or if you need more info in order to offer advice, please let me know. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Are you using a gallery? I mean, will every element of the gallery show a different custom title? .... or just want to open a single element with a different title from the one on the title attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, JFK, for you answer in another post. It was what I was looking for. Much appreciated ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1084188

> What I would do is to set the titles to appear in Fancybox in a hidden
>   DIV so my tooltip will show a different content from the title in
>   Fancybox:

```
<a rel="group" class="fancylink" href="images/01.jpg" title="default title 1">image 1</a>
<a rel="group" class="fancylink" href="images/02.jpg" title="default title 2">image 2</a>
<a rel="group" class="fancylink" href="images/03.jpg" title="default title 3">image 3</a>
```

> and the Fancybox titles:

```
<div id="fancyboxTitles" style="display: none;">
<div>fancybox title one</div>
<div>fancybox title two</div>
<div>fancybox title three</div>
```

> using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancylink").fancybox({ afterLoad : function() {this.title = $("#fancyboxTitles div").eq(this.index).html();}}); //fancybox}); // ready
```