# Add a title to fancybox without using title attritube to avoid yellow box?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

So I'm using fancybox and I want my iFrame boxes to have titles, but I don't want to use the title attribute in HTML because then I get that ugly yellow box on mouse over. Anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you want to give it a title then? That behavior is browser specific and can't be overridden.

Comment: Set the `title` content to `""` on hover, then set it back on mouse out.

Comment: You may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987 so you could remove the title attribute.