# Combining WordPress and Easy FancyBox with title AND description

Tags: fancybox, wordpress, lightbox

Client is requesting a Lightbox gallery which will, on click, provide image, description and page title. After extensive review of available Lightbox solutions, I am most leaning towards [Easy FancyBox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/), however upon review, the plugin does not support both title and description, as it only calls data from title="". I was able to locate [this code, which replaces the image title with WordPress' custom caption.](http://pastebin.com/5srPv35b) However, I am not looking to replace, but rather include both image title, description and perhaps the title of the WordPress page. Is there a relatively simple JQuery solution to this? Or should I be looking at other Lightbox solutions altogether?

I have also researched NextGEN Gallery, which is by far the most popular WordPress image gallery plugin, however this does not plug into WordPress' existing galleries, which I do not like at all. Any recommendations would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easyfancybox uses fancybox v1.3.4, which have some limitations, specifically the functionality you want.

If you are good at wordpress then you could hard-code fancybox v2.x in it (no plugin). Fancybox v2.x will allow you to have both titles and captions. See some examples here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987

You could actually get the captions from wp custom fields.

Of course, it also depends on your wordpress/php/jQuery skills ... but if you are developing for clients, I guess you shouldn't have issues with that  ;)