# How can I add text to Fancybox (other than title of thumb)?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am using the Fancybox Jquery plugin, and I want to have text, and a link to appear under the image in the box that pops up. I know that I can put text in the title="" of the thumbnail, but is there another way to add text? I don't like how the image caption is visible when the user hovers over the thumb.

Thx in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/FWTZA/
there is a link to it from this page http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/