# Fancybox Gallery AND Custom Titles

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to enter custom HTML as the title, like this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  padding: 0,
  title: '<a href="http://www.google.com">Hello</a>'
});
```

...but I also want a gallery of images.

I don't think you can have both as each gallery should use the same code above, but each unique title needs a separate implementation of the above code. Is this possible?

Also, is there a better way to set say 20 images, all in the same gallery and all with custom title content. At the moment I'm guessing I would need to specify each one individually using this code:

```
$("#fancybox-number-1").fancybox({
  padding: 0,
  title: 'custom-title-1'
});
```

(...but of course the gallery won't work and even if it did, specifying this 20 times sounds bad practice to me.)

How do I specify custom title, and have a gallery of 20 or so images in the best way possible?

Comment: The latest. Version: 2.0.6 (Thu, 19 Jul 2012) to be exact.

Comment: You could either do this

<http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987>

or this

<http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987>