# Fancy Box Title Tags

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am having one or two issues implementing the Fancy Box jQuery plugin onto my site and I was hoping someone could assist me.

I have created a sample page

http://www.csr500.co.uk/websites/v9/preview.html

Now my issue is relating to the title tag. I would like to remove the title tags on item hover, but when fancy box is launched I would like the title's to be visible as that is the description below the image in Fancy Box.

I have tried hiding the title attribute using jquery, however when you launch fancy box I get zero description under the image.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide the tooltip on hover from the title tag when using FancyBox 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610883/how-do-i-hide-the-tooltip-on-hover-from-the-title-tag-when-using-fancybox-2-0)

Comment: thanks for the tip, problem all sorted now, much appreciated