# Hiding <br> tags on image gallery thumbnail mouseover (fancybox)

Tags: jquery, fancybox, title, fancybox-2

I'm using a fancybox j-query gallery, which displays the 'title=' value under the image. I have 
 tags in the titles to separate the different descriptors of each image (dimensions, type of print, for sale/sold, etc.). It displays just fine inside the gallery, but when mousing over the thumbnails, the title is shown with the 
 tags visible.

How can I hide those 
 tags on mouseover, or is there a way to turn off the mouse-over function? Or

Many thanks.

url: http://kellydooley.com/test/portfolio.html

Comment: You can do either this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide the tooltip on hover from the title tag when using FancyBox 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610883/how-do-i-hide-the-tooltip-on-hover-from-the-title-tag-when-using-fancybox-2-0)